# Can I include only annotated classes in the ant fileset to work with?

Tags: java, ant

I want 2 ant tasks in the build file. Both of the tasks are for testing. The only separation between the two is in the test-classes that the must run. I was thinking if I can annotate one set of these tests, and ant could include/exclude depending on annotations, maintenance would be much easier for me. All the tests are in the same directory, I don't have authority to refactor the 2 sets into 2 separate directories.

For instance:

@alphaSet
Class A

@alphaSet
Class B

@betaSet
Class C

@betaSet
Class D

Is there a way to include only @alphaSet classes (or only @betaSet classes) in the fileset inside the test tasks of the build script?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fileset with [selector(s)](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html), f.e. :

```
<fileset dir="some/dir" includes="**/*.java" id="alphaSet">
 <contains text="@alphaSet" casesensitive="yes"/>
</fileset>

<fileset dir="some/dir" includes="**/*.java" id="betaSet">
 <contains text="@betaSet" casesensitive="yes"/>
</fileset>

<!-- control includes via echo -->
<echo>${toString:alphaSet}</echo>
<echo>${toString:betaSet}</echo>
```

if more criterias needed, use [selectorcontainers](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#selectcontainers) and/or/not .. , f.e. :

```
<fileset dir="some/dir" includes="**/*.java" id="alphaSet">
 <and>
  <contains text="@alphaSet" casesensitive="yes"/>
  <not>
    <!-- some other selectors ... -->
  </not>
  <and>
</fileset>
```

Comment: So until we can restructure the test folders, this will do the trick for me. Thanks a lot!